# How to compile C programs using cc command in cmd

Tags: c, assembly, cmd, compilation, mingw

I'd like to know how I can use cc compiler/assembler from cmd (I am on windows) to compile/assemble C programs.

I tried running the cc command on a .c file with MinGW and MSYS2 installed, and it did not work.

Comment: If your compiler is installed correctly, `cc foo.c` or `gcc foo.c` should make a working executable.  Perhaps you didn't add the bin directory to the PATH for the shell you're using?  Or you get some other error message you didn't show, since this isn't a [mcve] of what you tried.

Comment: "... and it did not work" is not a good problem description. Tells us the exact command used and tell us what happened.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to do this is to get a standalone build of MinGW-w64 for Windows from https://winlibs.com/.

This will provide you with all the tools you need to compile and link Windows programs.

The command will be `gcc` instead of `cc`, but to run it, you should specify its complete path. When the download is extracted you can find it under `mingw64\bin\gcc.exe`. Or you can add it to the `PATH` environment variable (but I don't recommend this).

There are examples on how to use it at https://winlibs.com/.

If you are a beginner it is recommended to use a GUI like VSCode or Code::Blocks, so you won't need command line actions to compile and link your code, and you can even debug your code if you need to.